# Qgis 1.9 issues with python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I already installed the version 1.9 of Qgis and when i runned e Script python on i could

this error   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'   however it works fine on qgis 1.8

could someone help me please !!

Comment: What Operating System are you working with?

Comment: the mine is Windows7

Answer (score 1):

Recently there were many changes made in QGIS Master for the upcoming QGIS 2.0 relase. Unfortunately some bugs may occur when running old scripts. It will be necessary to rewrite many python scripts designed for QGIS 1.8.

Best advice at the moment would be to stick to QGIS 1.8 until QGIS 2.0 is released.